# which one is larger, $g_1$ or $g_2$?

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, exponential-function, substitution

If I have a function $f(x)=x^n$ and $x>0$, $n>1$, there are four positive values $0<c<a<b<d$ which are satisfied the condition $c=a-m$ and $d=b+m$,  $m$ is a positive constant value. Here $g_1=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ and $g_2=\frac{f(d)-f(c)}{d-c}$.

$g_1$ and $g_2$ whcih one is larger.

Comment: Why did you delete the old question and post a new question that is nearly 100% identical?

Comment: The last one has unclear notation, this one I modified the notation. These two are different.

Comment: @Aeeh Next time just edit the original question.

Comment: Ok, I will, sorry to bother you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n>2$, $f(x)=\frac{(b+x)^n-(a-x)^n}{b-a+2x},$ where $0<x<a.$

Thus, we need to prove that $f$ increases, for which we need to prove that $$f'(x)>0$$ or
$$\frac{(n(b+x)^{n-1}+n(a-x)^{n-1})(b+x-(a-x))-2((b+x)^n-(a-x)^n)}{(b-a+2x)^2}>0$$ or
$$(n-2)(b+x)^n-(n-2)(a-x)^n+n(a-x)^{n-1}(b+x)-n(b+x)^{n-1}(a-x)>0.$$
Now, let $b+x=t(a-x).$

Thus, $t>1$ and we need to prove that $g(t)>0,$ where
$$g(t)=(n-2)t^n-(n-2)+nt-nt^{n-1}>0.$$
Indeed, by AM-GM
$$g'(t)=n(n-2)t^{n-1}+n-n(n-1)t^{n-2}=n\left((n-2)t^{n-1}+1-(n-1)t^{n-2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq n\left((n-1)\left(t^{(n-1)(n-2)}\cdot1\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}}-(n-1)t^{n-2}\right)=0.$$
The equality does not occur because $t>1$.

Id est, $g(t)>g(1)=0$ and we are done in this case.

The case $1<n<2$ is the similar.

Can you end it now?

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate your answer.